# Is echolocation common among the blind? Or not so much? How to learn to echolocate?

Tags: blind, auditory-cortex

We know that echolocation is common among the animal kingdom, e.g. bats, dolphins, etc., but I've read it's also possible among humans as well (granted, we are a part of the animal kingdom too).

I know humans do not emit sonar sound-waves, but I read that humans have the ability to echolocate on some level, and it makes sense that blind people are more likely to learn to echolocate than humans with the capacity to see, but **is it common for blind individuals to know how to echolocate? Stats?**

**Also, how do blind individuals learn to echolocate?** Is it something they pick up naturally because their hearing is sharper due to sensory substitute or are they trained to make clicking sounds? How does it work exactly? How can I learn?